# Chrome extension request notification permission on install

Tags: google-chrome-extension, push-notification, notifications

When I add notifications to my chrome extension, first i have to go to e.q. options.html page to get popup from chrome "Show notifications".
Is it possible to somehow display it in chrome extension popup or on extension install in chrome://extensions/?

Comment: I'm adding rich notifications to extension from chrome and to allow notification from extension I have to go to extension options page to grant permission. So is it possible to allow it from extension popup or from chrome://extensions/ page?

Comment: Apparently this is controlled by a global option in chrome settings and by default it's [Ask when a site wants to show notifications](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3220216). See also: [contentSettings API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSettings#property-notifications). I never saw such confirmation popups so I don't post this info as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just add the "notifications" permission. You may also need to use the chrome.notifications api instead of the web version.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications